# Typescript/Javascript load existing file without user interaction

Tags: javascript, file, typescript

I've seen many examples making use of

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
```

and then something like

```
let $img: any = document.querySelector('#file');

if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.pdfSrc = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer($img.files[0]);
}
```

However, I know the file path and I just want to get that without any user interaction.  In the example, `$img.files[0]` is a Blob, so it would seem that I would need to create a new `Blob` or `File` object from my known file path, but I can't figure out how to do that.  I do not want to create a new file, just an object from the existing file.  I would think this would be quite straight-forward, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something easy.  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like it would be a security hole if the browser let javascripts just load any file it liked, wouldn't it?

Comment: There is no way to select a file without the user selecting it.

Comment: So it sounds like the correct way to do this is to have javascript load the file from the server.

Comment: My search-fu must be weak today. I'm sure I've seen this question a dozen times; not finding them, though. Hopefully someone else will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. The user has to identify the file to load (via the `input type="file"`, drag-and-drop, etc.). You cannot pre-specify the filename, nor initiate the file load, without the user's intervention. It would be a massive security hole.

You can load files from your *server*, or from other servers allowing your origin via Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, but not from the user's machine.